# function with restrictions in finding solutions

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

Please help...

How to prove the following functional equation, which has no solution.

$A + B + C + (A + B)C - 2 = 0$ has no solution, where $A = f(x)$, $B = g(x)$ and $C = h(x)$. Here $A, B$ and $C$ are real functions and knowing that all functions are non-linear with the following conditions:

1) $2A = A + (B - C) A$

2) $4B = B + (C- A) B$

3) $6C = C + (A - B) C$

4) $A, B$ and $C$ are not equal to zero.

Prove that $A + B + C + (A + B)C - 2 = 0$ has no solution with respect to the above conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Part I: At least one has to be zero

Let $K_A := \{x \in \mathbb{R} | f(x) \neq 0\}$,  $K_B := \{x \in \mathbb{R} | g(x) \neq 0\}$ and $K_C := \{x \in \mathbb{R} | h(x) \neq 0\}$

### Condition 1

$\begin{align*}
    2A &= A + (B-C) \cdot A \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
\Leftrightarrow A &= (B-C) \cdot A \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
\Rightarrow     1 &= B-C \;\;\;\forall x \in K_A
\end{align*}$

### Condition 2

$\begin{align*}
    4B &= B + (C-A) \cdot B \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
 \Leftrightarrow 3B &=(C-A) \cdot B \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
 \Rightarrow 3 &= C-A\;\;\;\forall x \in K_B\\
\end{align*}$

### Condition 3

$\begin{align*}
    6C &= C + (A-B) \cdot C \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
 \Leftrightarrow 5C &=(A-B) \cdot C \;\;\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}\\
 \Rightarrow 5 &= A-B\;\;\;\forall x \in K_C\\
\end{align*}$

### Conclusion

$\forall x \in (K_A \cap K_B \cap K_C):$

$\begin{align}
C &= B - 1\\
\Rightarrow 3 &= (B-1) - A\\
\Rightarrow 5 &= A - B\\ 
\\
B &= 4 + A\\
\Rightarrow 5 &= A - (4+A) = -4\\
\end{align}
$

This is a contradiction $\Rightarrow K_A \cap K_B \cap K_C = \emptyset$

This means, there is no $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ and $g(x) \neq 0$ and $h(x) \neq 0$.

## Part II: Check cases

### Case 1: $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | C(x) = 0\}$

Condition is $A + B = 2$

$\begin{align}
2A &= A + AB \\
\Leftrightarrow A &= AB\\
\\
4B &= B - AB\\
\Leftrightarrow -3B &= AB\\
\\
A &= -3B
\end{align}$

Now you can simplify the condition:

$\begin{align}
-3B + B = -2B &= 2\\
\Leftrightarrow B &= -1\\
\Rightarrow A &= 3
\end{align}$

### Case 2: $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | B(x) = 0\}$

Condition is  $A + C + AC -2 = 0$

$\begin{align}
2A &= A - AC \\
\Leftrightarrow -A &= AC\\
\\
6C &= C + AC\\
\Leftrightarrow 5C &= AC\\
\\
\Rightarrow -A &= 5C\\
\Leftrightarrow A &= -5C
\end{align}$

Now you can simplify the condition:

$\begin{align}
A + C + AC -2 &= 0\\
\Leftrightarrow -5C + C + (-5C)C -2 &= 0\\
\Leftrightarrow -5 C^2 -4C  -2 &= 0\\
\Leftrightarrow C_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2 \cdot (-5)} \cdot \left (-4 \pm \sqrt{16 - 4 \cdot (-5) \cdot (-2)} \right )
\end{align}$

This means $C$ has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | B(x) = 0\} = \emptyset$

### Case 3: $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | A(x) = 0\}$

Condition is  $B+C+BC-2 = 0$

$\begin{align}
4B &= B + BC\\
\Leftrightarrow 3B &= BC\\
\\
6C &= C - BC\\
\Leftrightarrow 5C &= -BC\\
\Leftrightarrow -5C &= BC\\
\\
3B &= -5C\\
\Leftrightarrow B &= -\frac{5}{3}C
\end{align}$

Now you can simplify the condition:

$\begin{align}
-\frac{5}{3}C+C+(-\frac{5}{3}C)C-2 &= 0\\
-\frac{5}{3}C^2-\frac{2}{3}C-2 &= 0\\
\frac{5}{3}C^2+\frac{2}{3}C+2 &= 0\\
\Rightarrow C_{1,2} &= \frac{1}{2 \frac{5}{3}} \cdot \left (- \frac{2}{3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{9} - 4 \cdot \frac{5}{3} 2} \right )\\
&= \frac{3}{10} \cdot \left (- \frac{2}{3} \pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{9} - \frac{40}{3}} \right)
\end{align}$

This means $C$ has no solution in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $\{x \in \mathbb{R} | A(x) = 0\} = \emptyset$

## Bring it together

- $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) = 0 \text{ or } g(x) = 0 \text{ or } h(x) =  0$
- $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: f(x) \neq 0 \text{ and } g(x) \neq 0$
- $\Rightarrow \forall x \in \mathbb{R} : h(x) = 0$
- $\Rightarrow h = 0 \Leftrightarrow C = 0$
- $\Rightarrow$ contradiction
- $\Rightarrow$ there are no such real functions $f,g, h \blacksquare$

Comment: ! Excellent!very good explanation...

Comment: MOOSe! if you see part-II and case I, you have shown A = 3, B = -1 and C = 0. If you put these values in condition 1, 2, and 3, your values of A, B, C are not satisfied. Why? please explain.

Comment: @apeamcet: I think you just found a way to make this proof simpler. There is a contradiction (but as far as I can see no error in calculation), so this case cannot happen.

Answer (score 1):

The first three conditions can be written as
$$A\bigl(1-(B-C)\bigr)=0,\quad B\bigl(3-(C-A)\bigr)=0,\quad C\bigl(5-(A-B)\bigr)=0\ .\tag{1}$$
According to the fourth condition $A$, $B$, $C$ are all nonzero. Therefore from $(1)$ we can conclude that
$$1-(B-C)=0,\quad 3-(C-A)=0,\quad 5-(A-B)=0\ .$$
Adding these three equations together gives $9=0$. This signifies that your four conditions cannot be fulfilled simultaneously.

Comment: Wow ... that so much easier than my solution. (+1)

Comment: That's exactly what I did yesterday and the OP said I misunderstood the question, so I deleted my answer.